# Why does including a version query parameter on the URL matter when loading React through a CDN?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cdn

I just recently took over this very old project which I think loads a react component thru CDN.

Basically, the react component is built using webpack, and the minified ReactJS resides in `root/html/assets/scripts/`.

Now, in the twig file, it loads the components with this link:

```
https://cdn.example.com/assets/scripts/react/component.js?v=6.4.015
```

and note the version: **v=6.4.015**, all things worked perfectly when I leave the version at that, but when I change it to something else, it then spits `react minified errors`:

> Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`?v=6.4.015` acts as a cache buster. Any new parameter value forces the request to go through to the server for the most recent version of the document.

The error message has this bit in it:

> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

When you are using a CDN, it caches URLs (such as JavaScript files) at its edge nodes.  This makes the site faster for users and takes load off of your origin server.  The down side is that users may not get changes to the file when it is updated. Putting the version parameter on the URL causes the new version of the JS library to be cached under a different URL.